# Hosting .Net Core Web API using Topshelf

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1, self-hosting, topshelf

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Web API project which is currently hosted using IIS.

Is there a way to Host this web api in windows service Using TopShelf Nuget package as I don’t want to host it in IIS

If any reference document is available share that as it will be useful for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some wonderful documents from Microsoft MVP to explain how to running `Asp.Net Core` as Windows service by TopShelf. I hope it can help you.

Link: https://anthonygiretti.com/?s=Topshelf.